# How can you change the name of a colum in a GWT DataGrid?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT DataGrid with static columns. While I know I can remove columns and add them back with different names, is it possible to just change a column's name directly?

Update:

I don't understand what's going on. Per Thomas Boyer's answer below, I do see in the docs that .getHeader() is inherited from AbstractCellTable as a public method, but the compiler says no such method exists for DataGrid.

Grid is created:

```
DataGrid myGrid = new DataGrid<MyType>(Integer.MAX_VALUE, GWT.<DataGridResources2> create(DataGridResources2.class));
```

And this fails to compile:

```
Header<MyHeaderClass> header = myGrid.getHeader(0);
```

Compiler says no such method exists for type DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the suggested answer is unworkable because the setValue method doesn't just take a String or SafeHtml - you need stuff like a Context, etc.

Here's a way to do it:

```
public class HeaderHtml implements SafeHtml {
   /**
    * the header's HTML string
    */
   private String html = "";

   /**
    * Sets the HTML after escaping tags.
    * Could change to:
    *    this.html = html == null ? "" : html;
    * if desired.
    */
   public void setHtml(String html) {
      this.html = html == null ? "" : SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscapeAllowEntities(html);
   }

   /**
    * Required method to deliver the HTML string
    * @return the HTML string
    */
   @Override
   public String asString() {
      return html;
   }
}
```

Create an instance of that to use as a SafeHtml header.  Then you can push a new string in any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getHeader](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#getHeader(int)) method of DataGrid to obtain column header, and then

```
getCell().setValue
```

Comment: A GWT DataGrid does not have a getHeader() method.

Comment: @CBass WAT? `DataGrid` extends `AbstractCellTable`, `AbstractCellTable` has a `getHeader` (see link in the answer)

Comment: I do see in the docs that getHeader is publicly inherited from AbstractCellTable, but the compiler says it not defined for type DataGrid.